# ESRI JS API - Unable to register Basemap Gallery (ID is already registered)

Tags: dojo, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am attempting to add a BasemapGallery to my web application. I prefer to create my layout dynamically using constructors such as:

```
layout.cpRight = new ContentPane({
    region:"right",
    ...
    ...
});

layout.borderContainer.addChild(layout.cpRight);
```

This is functioning fine and my layout is placed as it should.

The probleme is When I attempt to add basemapGallery with the bellow code:

```
maps.basemapGalleryParams = {
    showArcGISBasemaps:true,
    map: maps.map,
};

maps.basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery(maps.basemapGalleryParams,layout.cpRight);
maps.basemapGallery.startup();
```

I get the following Error Code: **init.js.160**

> Error: Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0
>   but that id is already  registered(…) "in domReady callback" "Error:
>   Tried to register widget with  id==dijit_layout_ContentPane_0 but that
>   id is already registered

I originally declared ids inside of the widget constructors parameter but removed when I got this error. The results where the same.

A few web searches indicate this can be a fairly common problem with some "easy" solutions but I have not found a solution where the layout is declared programaticly  as I would like to. It seems many defer to declare components in HTML.

Side note: 
I break out applications into multiple scripts thus I create arrays to ensure certain variables are global across all scripts. Hence why in the scripts above, things are not being declared with the var keyword, but rather directly appending to the array.

Comment: This might be an order-of-operations error. Can you edit your answer so we can see the code flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incorrect to assign a dijit in Refnode param `BasemapGallery(maps.basemapGalleryParams,layout.cpRight);`.

So, you have to a assing a dom node in that params , in your case to prevent the `BaseMaapGallery` dijit to replace the `contentPane` you need to create div using `dojo/dom-construct` inside the `contentPane` and put the `BaseMapGallery` there .

Note that in dojo every Dijits has a `containerNode` attribute which refer to the contained domNode of that dijit , by exemple the contenier node of you contentePane is `layout.cpRightFirst.containerNode`

dont forget to import (require) the `dojo/dom-construct` :

here is the code :

```
require([
      ...
      "dojo/dom-construct",
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(....
      domConstruct
    ) {
    ...
    ...
    maps.basemapGalleryParams = {
        showArcGISBasemaps:true,
        map: maps.map,
    };

    maps.basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery(maps.basemapGalleryParams,
                                             domConstruct.create("div", null, layout.cpRight.containerNode));
    maps.basemapGallery.startup();
    ...
    ...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a best practice solution, however I was able to come up with a work around.

```
maps.basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery(maps.basemapGalleryParams,"bg");
layout.cpBasemap.addChild(maps.basemapGallery);
```

For the srcNode parameter I used an arbitrary string that is not an id to anything in the application. Then used addChild() to place it in the existing widget desired.

Comment: The `srcNode` parameter is optional, so you don't need anything there if you're placing it later in the code.

Comment: That was my initial thought, however for whatever reason the gallery will not draw unless I place a value for the srcNode. Strange...